# How do I disable Microsoft Diagnostic Tool (MSDT) entirely?

Tags: windows, remote-access

There was a recently published exploit using URIs to open MSDT and execute arbitrary code. [Microsoft's suggestion](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2022/05/30/guidance-for-cve-2022-30190-microsoft-support-diagnostic-tool-vulnerability/) was to delete the registry key corresponding to the `ms-msdt://` protocol.

Unfortunately, this still leaves MSDT active and presumably exploitable via other routes. Personally, I have never used MSDT, nor would I ever need to. Searching how to disable MSDT (results filtered to before May 1, 2022) gave me this result on how to [disable MSDT from communicating with Microsoft](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_7/2014-04-02/finding/V-21967):

> Registry Hive: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
>
> Subkey: `\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ScriptedDiagnosticsProvider\Policy\`
>
> Value Name: `DisableQueryRemoteServer`
>
> Type: `REG_DWORD`
>
> Value: `0`

However, I didn't find any further results. Is there a way to disable MSDT entirely? Would simply deleting msdt.exe actually impact the system's stability?

Comment: You have never clicked the n a link on a website to run a Microsoft Windows troubleshooting tool? That’s effectively what MSDT allows you to do. It’s extremely doubtful it responds to any other URL which is the reason the suggested solution is to disable it

Comment: @Ramhound wasn't aware that troubleshooter links ran MSDT, but nowadays I would not click random links to run a troubleshooter. The few times I did that in the past from MS documentation didn't help much anyway. Windows 10 is EoL in a few years and I don't plan on upgrading to Win11 due to TPM requirements, so I don't think I will use MSDT again - I'd rather just close off that attack vector entirely.

Comment: I want to know is it safe to delete `msdt.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32`?

Comment: Anybody knows how to delete this piece of crap? It's asking for TrustedInstaller privilege

Comment: @fmnijk you can but it will get recreated when you install any monthly update

Comment: @pma_ you can change permissions and ownership on it as mentioned here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753659(v=ws.11)

Answer (score 1):

I think that in theory you could try and change the permissions to `%WINDOWS%\System32\msdt.exe` by removing execution rights temporarily. But this is no guarantee, that the functionality itself isn't accessable via other calls via API. But at least nobody should be able to run it from command prompt.

Comment: Unfortunately the monthly updates will restore this tool, so this solution doesn't work